# Redirect ActiveMQ web console with HAProxy

Tags: activemq-classic, haproxy

I am new to HAProxy and I am trying to do a simple redirect from `<server_ip>/mq` to `<server_ip>:8161/admin`

When I am trying to access ActiveMQ directly via `<server_ip>:8161/admin` everything works well.

But with the HAProxy sometimes I get `503`. And when it works it doesn't load the resources at all (no css, no images..)

```
frontend http
        bind *:80
        timeout client 60s
        mode http
        acl app path_end -i /mq
        use_backend appServer if app
        default_backend all

backend appServer
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout server 10s
        mode http
        http-request set-path /admin/
        server servermq <server_ip>:8161

backend all
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout server 10s
        mode http
        http-request set-path /admin/
        server servermq <server_ip>:8161
```

In the dev tools I can see errors like this:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://<server_ip>/admin/styles/site.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

But I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: So you're just trying to access the ActiveMQ web console via HAProxy?

Comment: @JustinBertram 
yes, Rahul answer fix this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's address the issues one by one.

1. **Intermittent 503**

   This is most likely due to more than one `haproxy` processes running in the system. You can find all of them by a simple `ps -ef | grep haproxy`. Kill all but one and it should be fixed. Another reason might be due to two `frontend`s binding on same port which in this case is **:80**. Check for all the `frontend` where binding port is 80. Change each one of them to be different from the other.
2. **CSS and JS not loading which is related to the mismatched MIME type error posted**

   There is an issue with your haproxy configuration in the `backend all` section. According to your `frontend http` rules, all request ending with `/mq` should go to `backend appServer` where a url rewrite is happening via `http-request set-path /admin/`. `/mq` is replaced with `/admin/` before sending it to `servermq`. This is correct but when you're loading the activemq admin in the browser, the browser is making requests for *.css and *.js files which is coming empty. This is because the browser is making request on `/admin/styles/sorttable.css` file. Now this doesn't match with your `acl app` but goes to `default_backend all`. Here due to this rule `http-request set-path /admin/` again path is set to `/admin/` which returns 200 but without any css file, that's why the error:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://<server_ip>/admin/styles/site.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

The correct config should be:

```
frontend http
    bind *:80
    timeout client 60s
    mode http
    acl app path_end -i /mq
    use_backend appServer if app
    default_backend all

backend appServer
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 10s
    mode http
    http-request set-path /admin/
    server servermq <server_ip>:8161

backend all
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 10s
    mode http
    server servermq <server_ip>:8161
```